# Google Voice is not working on Android Emulator

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I am building an app that recognizes the voice and words and responds accordingly.I am running Android Emulator-Nexus_5X_API_25:5554

But when I start the Emulator and touch the speak button It just says Try Again and Try Again.By the way there is no error in the code as the problem is also with the google app,as when I push the sound button on Google App the same error appears.

Comment: Are you using Android emulator with Google APIs?

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that.I am a newbie in Android Studio.Please help.

Comment: On Android Studio go to Tools>Android>AVD Manager, then click on "Create Virtual Device". After selecting the device and clicking on next, choose a system image which has "(Google APIs)" in its target.

Comment: Did it.But still not working@SinaMasnadi

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but try to use Genymotion or any other Android emulator alternatives.

Comment: Anyone else who had the same problem or knows how to deal with it?

Comment: facing the similar issue, it says "Network not Connected" but i am able to use everything(Internet on browser,playstore..etc) on the device except this.